# Onchange events in JSP loaded using JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I  have a parent JSP in which i am loading a child jsp using jquery

```
function changeContent() {
    $('#msHotTopics').load('msHotTopics.jsp');
}
```

parent jsp

```
<!------------------- Home page content ----------------------->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
<td style="padding: 12px 20px 20px 20px;width: 100%;" valign="top">
    <widget:searchEntry action="searchEntry.do" template="searchentry_new.vm"
        searchType="gs" showsavesearch='false' showSavedSearches='true'
        widgetid='kcchp' showclear='false' searchdocuments="Authored,KSM,Forums"
        useWorkbench='true'
        message='<%=ResourceHelper.getMessage( "kanisa", locale, "label.authoring.searchEntryMessage" )%>'
        example=""
        RWTarget="/rfPlayerWidget.do">
<%-- 
  TW30584 Please be aware that microsite home and search pages should have identical <Parameters>
 and each <Parameter> or <UMPageletParameter> <name> should be unique.
 If you want to have UM Browser for product you should comment <Parameter> with name "product", uncomment <UMPageletParameter>
 and set <name> "product" and <umType> SG_SupportGoals for <UMPageletParameter>
--%>              
                    <Parameters>
                    <Parameter>
                    <name>searchFor</name>
                    <constraint>no</constraint>
                    <attributes>string,advlist</attributes>
                    <defvalues>all</defvalues>
                    </Parameter>
                    <Parameter>
                    <name>author</name>
                    <constraint>no</constraint>
                    <defvalues></defvalues>
                    <attributes>string,advtext</attributes>
                    </Parameter>

<%--
                    <UMPageletParameter>
                        <umType>SG_SupportGoals</umType>
                        <columns>1</columns>
                        <name>product</name>
                        <constraint>no</constraint>
                        <attributes>string,filter,advlistmultiple,gslist</attributes>
                        <defvalues></defvalues>


                        <guidedModeUMPageletParameters>
                                <height>315</height>
                                <defaultMode>browse</defaultMode>
                                <searchDivWidth>380</searchDivWidth>
                                <treeDivWidth>380</treeDivWidth>
                                <selectedWidth>160</selectedWidth>
                                <treeAndSearchDivHeight>280</treeAndSearchDivHeight>
                                <showSelectedControlInRow>true</showSelectedControlInRow>
                                <selectedListSize>15</selectedListSize>
                                <showWhat><%=UMConstants.ShowIncludedItemsMode.NAME%></showWhat>
                                <selectionMode><%=UMConstants.SelectionModes.MULTIPLE%></selectionMode>
                        </guidedModeUMPageletParameters>

                        <advancedModeUMPageletParameters>
                                <width>430</width>
                                <height>450</height>
                                <defaultMode>browse</defaultMode>
                                <searchDivWidth>350</searchDivWidth>
                                <treeDivWidth>400</treeDivWidth>
                                <selectedWidth>320</selectedWidth>
                                <treeAndSearchDivHeight>280</treeAndSearchDivHeight>
                                <showSelectedControlInRow>false</showSelectedControlInRow>
                                <selectedListSize>4</selectedListSize>
                                <showWhat><%=UMConstants.ShowIncludedItemsMode.NAME%></showWhat>
                        </advancedModeUMPageletParameters>
                    </UMPageletParameter>
--%>

                    <Parameter>
                    <name>publicationstatus</name>
                    <constraint>no</constraint>
                    <values></values>
                    <valuenames></valuenames>
                    <defvalues>all</defvalues>
                    <attributes>string,advlist</attributes>
                    </Parameter>
                    <Parameter>
                    <name>product</name>
                    <constraint>SG_SupportGoals</constraint>
                    <attributes>string,filter,advlistmultiple,gslist,gsright</attributes>
                    <defvalues></defvalues>
                    <sortOrder>configured</sortOrder>                        
                    </Parameter>
                    <Parameter>
                    <name>document</name>
                    <constraint>DT_DocType</constraint>
                    <attributes>string,filter,advlistmultiple</attributes>
                    <defvalues></defvalues>
                    <sortOrder>configured</sortOrder>                        
                    </Parameter>
                    <Parameter>
                    <name>datepublished</name>
                    <constraint>PUBLISHEDDATE</constraint>
                    <values></values>
                    <valuenames></valuenames>
                    <defvalues></defvalues>
                    <attributes>date,advinterval</attributes>
                    </Parameter>
                    <Parameter>
                    <name>locale</name>
                    <constraint>no</constraint>
                    <defvalues></defvalues>
                    <attributes>string,advlist</attributes>
                    </Parameter>
                    <%--
                    <Parameter>
                    <name>archivestate</name>
                    <controlname>Archive State:</controlname>
                    <constraint>UMAS_ArchiveState</constraint>
                    <defvalues></defvalues>
                    <attributes>string,filter,advlist,gslist,gsright</attributes>
                    </Parameter>
                    --%>
                    </Parameters>
    </widget:searchEntry>

   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" style="padding-top: 12px">
    <tr>

    <td  valign=top  style="padding: 14px 10px 0px 0px;">
        <div  id="msproducts"></div>
    </td>       

    <td>
    <table>
    <tr colspan="2" style="float: left;">
    <td width="100%" valign="top" style="padding: 10px;">
        <div id="msrecommendation"></div> 

        <div id="mssavedItemsWidget"></div>
    <br>    

    </td>   

    <td width="380" valign="top" style="padding: 10px;">
        <div id="msHotTopics"></div>        

    <br>
        <div id="msrwIncidentsWidget"></div> 

     <BR>
        <div id="msbrowseanswerwizards"></div>
     <BR>
    <%
    if (!loggedInUser.equals("guest") && !loggedInUser.equals(anonymousUsername)){
    %>
        <div id="mssubscriptionlist"></div>
    <br>
    <%
      }
    %>

</td>

</tr>
</table>  
    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<!--Auto suggest -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    if(<%=autoFillEnabled%>){
        hintsFetcherURL = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/autoFill/AutoFillServlet";
        maxsuggestions = <%=noOfSuggestions%>;
        autoComplt.enable(oGSSearchInput, {                 
                hintsFetcher : hintsFetcher
        }); 

        autoComplt.enable(oAdvSearchInput, {                    
                hintsFetcher : hintsFetcher
        }); 
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

mshottopics.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" session="true" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>

<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-bean" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/jstl-c" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/widgets" prefix="widget" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/jstl-fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

<fmt:setBundle basename="resources/application" var="kanisa" />

<html>
<head>
    <title><bean:message key='label.common.title'/></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-store">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="Now">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
    <link href="../css/knova.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body style="width: 380px; margin: 0px;">   
    <widget:search action="microsite.do" template="GS.vm"
                   showBrowseArea="none" showSearchWithin="false" showNavigationArea="false" showSynopsis="Title" hideDocType="true" 
                   widgetName="dd_home" widgetTitle="searchwidget.hotTopics"
                   UMFilterUMType="DT_DocType"  showUMFilter="true"  searchDocuments="KSM,Authored,Threaded"
                   sortDDL="newest,popular" sortCriteria="newest" numChar="100"
                   numDocsPerPage="5" useMSPreferences="true" />
</body>
</html>
```

Within the child jsp, there is Velocity template  with dropdown, the onchange event  of  the dropdown is not working.

Any ideas why this would happen? How to fix this?

Comment: Please show us more code.

Comment: Added the code now can you please suggest anything